# HashSet my class doesn't contain issue

Tags: c#, class, hashmap, equality, hashset

I have a class that is similar to this:

```
public class Int16_2D
{
    public Int16 a, b;

    public override bool Equals(Object other)
    {
        return other is Int16_2D &&
        a == ((Int16_2D)other).a &&
        b == ((Int16_2D)other).b;
    }
}
```

This works in `HashSet<Int16_2D>`. However in `Dictionary<Int16_2D, myType>`, `.ContainsKey` returns false when it shouldn't. Am I missing something in my implementation of `==`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c

Comment: Note that you're not actually implementing `==`, `Equals()` is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `GetHashCode()`. The fact that it works with `HashSet<T>` is probably just a lucky coincidence.

Both collections use the hash code obtained from `GetHashCode` to find a bucket (ie. list of objects), where the object should be placed. Then it searches that bucket to find the object, and uses `Equals` to ensure equality. This is what gives the nice fast lookup properties of the Dictionary and HashSet. However, this also means, that if `GetHashCode` is not overridden so that it corresponds to the types `Equals` method, you will not be able to find such an object in one of the collections.

You should, almost always, implement both `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, or none of them.

Answer (score 3):

For a class to work in a hash table or dictionary, you need to implement `GetHashCode()`!  I have no idea why it's working in HashSet; I would guess it was just luck.

Note that *it's dangerous to use mutable fields for calculating Equals or GetHashCode()*.  Why?  Consider this:

```
var x = new Int16_2D { a = 1, b = 2 };
var set = new HashSet<Int16_2D> { x };

var y = new Int16_2D { a = 1, b = 2 };
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(y));   // True

x.a = 3;
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(y));   // False
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(x));   // Also false!
```

In other words, when you set `x.a = 3;` you're changing x's hash code.  But x's location in the hash table is based on its *old* hash code, so x is basically lost now.  See this in action at http://ideone.com/QQw08

Also, as svick notes, implementing `Equals` does not implement `==`.  If you don't implement `==`, the `==` operator will provide a reference comparison, so:

```
var x = new Int16_2d { a = 1, b = 2 };
var y = new Int16_2d { a = 1, b = 2 };
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));             //True
Console.WriteLine(x == y);                  //False
```

In conclusion, you're better off making this an immutable type; since it's only 4 bytes long, I'd probably make it an immutable struct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `GetHashCode` as well for the dictionary to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `GetHashCode()` as well - this goes hand in hand with overriding `Equals`. Dictionary is using `GetHashCode()` to determine what bin a value would fall into - only if a suitable item is found in that bin it checks on actual equality of the items.